# Equivalent of $e^{-x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

> Let $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ and write $f^{(n)}(x)=P_n(x)f(x)$ where $P_n$ are polynomials.
>
> Then find an equivalent for $P_n(x)$ for every fixed positive $x$.

My attempt :

$f(x)=\exp(x^2) \quad f'(x)=2x\exp(x^2) \quad f''(x)=2\exp(x^2)(1+x^2)$

So $f''(x)-xf'(x)+2x^2f(x)=0$

It's a second order differential equation but I am not sure that it help here, perhaps the solution are the polynomial $P_n$ ?

I cannot generalize the derivative so I guess is there exsit an other approach I cannot find it by myself.

Thank you in advance

Comment: $$P_n(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi} _2 \tilde{F}_2(1, -n;\frac{1-n}{2}, 1-\frac{n}{2};-x^2))}{x^n}\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$$ Where $\tilde{F}$ is the regularized generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Can you post how did you get that please ? Thanks

Comment: @Edwin Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This almost coincides with the Rodrigues representation of [Hermite polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html) $H_n(x)$. In fact (see formula (19) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html)):
$$H_n(x)=(-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}.$$
Therefore we can identify
$$\boxed{\displaystyle \;P_n(x)=i^{-n}H_n(ix)\;^{\;}}$$
For explicit series representations, see formulas (41) and (43) from the same link.

Comment: Very slick (+1).

Comment: Thanks but I do not see how can I find an equivalent ? By using the series representations ?

Comment: @FreeX Yes. Also, one has integral representations and recurrence relations.